# replace a String (in some cases) in java

Tags: java, string, replace

if i have for example `String a = "8sin(30)+sin(40) + 3sin(30)"
String b = a;`how I can replace only the first "sin" and the third for "*sin", mantaining the second "sin" the same?
in other word, how I can replace part of a string only in specific cases?

Comment: Did you even take a look at the string manipulation methods?

Comment: @m02ph3u5 for example? ( i have read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html but I have not found a solution)

Comment: You only want to replace a "sin" with a prepending digit?

Comment: substring and concatenation or regular expressions or replace* methods ... there's enough tools

Comment: If you're looking to be able to do this in a single statement, you probably shouldn't.  Even if you can come up with a whiz-bang regular expression that you can use, it will likely be too difficult to understand.  The best code will probably be a combination of a simple regular expression (or even simpler string search) and loop.  However, you're not clear on just what you mean by "specific cases"--do you always want to replace the first and third occurrences, or is there some other condition you're looking for?  So it's hard to come up with a specific answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace `sin` which have number before it you can use something like

```
yourString = yourString.replaceAll("(\\d+)sin","$1*sin");
```

`replaceAll` uses regular expression which represents

- `\\d+` string build from one or more digit characters (like `0`, `12`, `321`...) - we will place this number in group 1
- `sin` literal.

In replacement we are reusing match from group 1 via `$1`

Demo:

```
String a = "8sin(30)+sin(40) + 3sin(30)";
System.out.println(a.replaceAll("(\\d)+sin","$1*sin"));
```

Output: `8*sin(30)+sin(40) + 3*sin(30)`

---

You can also use look-behind to check if before `sin` there is any digit

```
String a = "8sin(30)+sin(40) + 3sin(30)";
System.out.println(a.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)sin","*sin"));
```

Comment: it resolve my problem but I don't undersand what is $1

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi It is reference to match stored by regex in group indexed as 1. In this case it is match from `(\\d+)` part of the regex.

Comment: so if I write `a.replaceAll("(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,sqrt,^\\d)sin", "*sin")` is correct?

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi Probably not. Anyway you need to tell more about what you want to do (and please don't tell me you are building parser).

Comment: `operation.replaceAll("[0-9 && e && π && ! && )] + sin", "$1*sin");` is this correct?

Comment: I suspect that you may be searching for `[0-9eπ!)]`. `&&` is used to find intersection of character sets.

Comment: if i have `String a = "8sin(30)` and I write `a = a.replaceAll([0-9] + sin, "$1*sin)` `a` doesn't became `8*sin(30)` why?

Comment: There can be few reasons. First of all this code doesn't compile (arguments must be strings). If you meant `a = a.replaceAll("[0-9] + sin", "$1*sin");` then there are two problems here: (1) you added spaces in regex, and space is valid character so ` +` represents one or more spaces. So your regex will search for things like `1  sin` or `12  sin`, but not `1sin`; (2) there is no group 1 in your regex (to create group you need parenthesis). If you want to learn more about regex you should visit http://regular-expressions.info/ and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: i have partly resolved my problem... but if I write `String a = "(3-2)sin(30)"; a.replaceAll("([0-9eπ!)])+sin", "$1*sin");` my output is `(3-)*sin(30)`

Comment: You forgot `a = ` part in `a = a.replaceAll("([0-9eπ!)])sin", "$1*sin");`. Strings are immutable, so since `replaceAll` can't change original string, it creates new one, which you need to store somewhere (probably in reference `a` holding original string).

Comment: finally i (you) have resolved my problem... thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the [`replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method of String.

You can use below regex:

```
[0-9]+sin
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dV8rB7/1)

```
b=b.replaceFirst("[0-9]+sin","*sin");
```

Also you can use the [substring(int beginIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) method.

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi:- You need to provide more details. As in your present case replaceFirst method will work fine.

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi What are the rules of replacement? How do you determine which one you want to replace and which should stay?

Comment: if there is a number before "sin" i want to replace for "*sin" @Pshemo

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi:- You can try to use this regex in that case: `[0-9]+sin`

Comment: @Pshemo for example if I have "8sin(30)+sin(40) + 3sin(30)" i want to replace only the first and the third "sin"... but always the string is different (depend on what i want to calculate"

Comment: @GabrieleMarcozzi:- Updated my answer!